# Why is the erase function not working in this code?

Tags: c++, c++14

I have a two vectors with n elements. Now I have sorted the vectors and I want to delete the last element from the 1st vector and the second last element from the second vector. But this code is not working.

I have tried the below code. But the erase or even the pop_back vector is not working. It just prints same as that of the sorted vector and no effect of the erase function.

```
    v.erase(v.begin()+n-1);
    v1.erase(v1.begin()+n-2); 
    for(i=0;i<n;i++){
        cout<<v[i];
    }
    for(i=0;i<n;i++){
        cout<<v1[i];
    }
```

Example- If I have a vector 2 2 1 5..after sorting, 1 2 2 5. I want to delete last i.e. 5 and it should be 1 2 2. But after the above code, it still prints 1 2 2 5

Comment: Please post a minimal, complete, and verifiable example - that is, a complete program that we can compile and run that will demonstrate the problem, without having to add "#include" or "int main" or anything else ourself.

Comment: When creating the [mcve] please note that you only really need *one* vector to demonstrate the problem, and if you initialize the vector with a sorted list, you can skip the sorting.

Comment: Did you try to check the vector size?

Comment: Hint: How many elements do you expect the vectors to have after you have erased one of the n elements?

Comment: Yet another reason to prefer for-range.

Comment: The erase function is working fine. Your printing loop is wrong, and accesses elements past the end of both vectors.

Comment: Oh I got it now. Sorry for disturbing with unnecessary questions. I will delete it

Comment: @AkashRoy _" I will delete it"_ You can't and you shouldn't. There's an upvoted answer for your question. Be aware to improve your question instead, otherwise you'll be dragged to a [question ban](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/255583/what-can-i-do-when-getting-we-are-no-longer-accepting-questions-answers-from-th).

Answer (score 2):

It looks like `n` should have been updated, but was not, so you still print the (erased) element.